# load more content when scroll at bottom using wordpress and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cordova, jquery-mobile

im developping an app using cordova as platform for building apps and wordpress with JSON API plugin installed as backend .
i wrote this two functions to grab posts from my website and then show it to the user when the jquery mobile and cordova are fully loaded .

```html
// App Logic
function init()
{
 getData(1);
}
function getData(pageNumber) {
 $.getJSON('http://blabla.com/wordpress/?json=get_recent_posts&page='+pageNumber, function(data) {
  posts = data.posts;
  $.each(posts, function(index, post) {
   id = post.id;
   title = post.title;
   thumb = post.thumbnail;
   comments = post.comment_count;
   author  = post.author['name'];
     $('#posts_list').append('<a href="post.html?id='+id+'" data-ajax="false"><div class="single-post">'
     +'<div class="img"><img src="'+thumb+'" class="lazy" title="" /></div>'
     +'<div class="info">'
     +'<div class="title">'+title+'</div>'
     +'<div class="stats"><span class="author">'+author+'</span> <span class="comments">'+comments+' comments</span></div>'
     +'</div>'
     +'</div></a>');
  });
    
 });
}
```

i want when the user scroll at bottom page the code load more content of the page 2 untill the posts are fully loaded .
PS : this is an exmplade of the output on the server side (JSON) :

```html
<!-- http://blabla.com/?json=get_recent_posts&page=1-->
{"status":"ok","count":10,"count_total":2039,"pages":204,"posts":[{.....}] }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is on every scroll event check the distance from the current position to the bottom of the page or container and if the delta is smaller than what certain threshold you can append more items.

```
var count = 0,
    loadThreshold = 50; //50px threshold used to define when it needs to load more items.

loadContent();

$( window ).scroll(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      containerHeight = $(document).height(),
      contentCurrentTopPosition = $(document).scrollTop(),
      deltaDistanceToContentBottom = containerHeight - windowHeight - contentCurrentTopPosition;


    if (deltaDistanceToContentBottom < loadThreshold){
        loadContent();
    }

});


function loadContent(){
    var strContent = "",
        strTemplate = "<li>Item {0}</li>";
    for (var i=0;i<50;i++){
        strContent += strTemplate.replace('{0}',  count + i);
    }

    count += 50;
    $('.list').append(strContent);
}
```

(edited)
http://jsfiddle.net/bg88q6yL/3/

Remember that on the mobile devices the scroll event is executed only when the scrolling event starts and ends, so probably you will have some delay until the user finish scrolling.

Comment: can you be more clear please? i have some code to make things clear if you could please rewrite my code to make changes and post it again so i can learn?

Comment: sure, i changed a bit the code to simulate the methods that you are using:

http://jsfiddle.net/bg88q6yL/3/

Let me know if it makes more sense.